# How to pass actions down to the components in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx, react-router-redux

I want to fire an action down in my component. This is a presentation component and need not be redux aware. Router implementation is done using react-router-redux.

main.js:

```jsx
let store = createStore(rootReducer)

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(hashHistory, store)

class RenderClass extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={history}>
                <Route path="/" component={MainLayout}>
                    <Route name="employees" path="/employees" url="http://localhost:8080/" component={EmployeeTable}></Route>
                    <Route name="personalInformation" path="/personalInformation/:employeeId" url={URI} component={PersonalInformation} />
                    .....
                </Route>
            <Router>
        </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

App.jsx:

```jsx
import * as Actions from './action-creator';
const MainLayout = React.createClass({
                render: function() {

                    const { dispatch, list } = this.props;
                    let actions = bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch);
                    console.log(actions);

                    return (
                        <div className="wrapper">
                            <Header actions={actions} list={list} params={this.props.params} />

                    {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            }); 

function select(state) {
   return {
      list: state.listingReducer
   }
}
export default connect(select)(MainLayout);
```

header.js:

```jsx
define(
    [
        'react',
        'jquery',
        'appMin'
    ],
    function (React, $) {
        var Link = require('reactRouter').Link;
        var Header = React.createClass({
            handleClick: function () {
                //Action called here
                this.props.actions.listEmployees();
            },      
            render: function () {
                return (
                    <ul className="sidebar-menu">
                        <li>
                            <Link to={'/employees'} onClick={this.handleClick}><i className="fa fa-home"></i>Employees</Link> 
                        </li> 
                    </ul>
                );
            }
        });
        return Header;
    }
)
```

employee.js:

```jsx
define(
    [
        'react',
        'jquery',
        'appMin'
    ],
    function (React, $) {
        var EmployeeTable = React.createClass({

            render: function () {
                if (this.props.list != undefined) {
                    var listItems = this.props.list.map(function (listItem) {
                        return (
                            <tr key={listItem.id}>
                                <td> {listItem.name}</td>
                <td><Link to={'/personalInformation/' + employee.id} onClick={this.props.actions.displayPersonalInformation(employee.id)}>Personal Information</Link></td>
                                ......
                            </tr>
                        );
                    }, this);   
                    })
                }
                return (
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            {listItems}
                        </tbody>                    
                    </table>
                );
            }
        })  
    }
)
```

action-creator.js:

```jsx
export function listEmployees() {
    return {
      type: types.LIST_EMPLOYEES
   };
}

export function displayPersonalInformation() {
        return {
          type: types.DISPLAY_PERSONAL_INFORMATION
       };
    }

reducer.js:
function addEmployee(state, action) {

   switch (action.type) {

      case types.LIST_EMPLOYEES:
         return {"id":"1", "name":"Stackoverflow"}

      default:
        return state
   }
}

function listingReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case types.LIST_EMPLOYEES:
            return [
                ...state, 
                addEmployee(undefined, action)
            ]

        case types.DISPLAY_PERSONAL_INFORMATION:
                return // Gets personal Information

        default:
            return state;
    }
}


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   listingReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

The props will not contain actions since I have not tied it to props. I tried writing mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps in **App.js** as shown below:

```jsx
function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {
        list: state.list
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
   return { actions: bindActionCreators({ actionCreators }, dispatch) }
}
```

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainLayout)
I'm getting dispatch is not a function error. The error statement actually sounds like a duplicate question in stackoverflow, but I would also like to know the purpose why I'm using mapDispatchToProps is also right. Thanks in advance.

Comment: On which part od code your getting this error?

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran: I'm getting this error in mapDispatchToProps function and after the action is fired. More than the error, I would like to know what am I supposed to do when I'm supposed to use an action in presentation component when redux router is used.

Answer (score 5):

So from what I understand you are using `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainLayout)` and trying to call `dispatch` in `MainLayout`.

So from the react-redux documentation if you see you can call connect in following ways:-

- `connect()(//Component)`  --> dispatch would be passed as props
- `connect(mapStateToProps)(//Component)` --> dispatch would be passed as props
- `connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(//Component)` --> **dispatch would not be passed as props to your component**

In scenario 3 the behavior is this way because `mapDispatchToProps` already has access to dispatch function. So you can bind your function to dispatch in `mapDispatchToProps` and then pass on this function to your component.

**Example**

The function you want to dispatch are `dispatchMe()` and `dispatchMe2()` which calls an action called `dispatchAction`. So your `mapDispatchToProps` would be something like :-

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return {
     dispatchMe : () => {
       dispatch(dispatchAction()) 
    },
    dispatchMe2 : () => {
      dispatch(dispatchAction2())
    }
  }
}
```

Now in your component you can pass `dispatchMe` and call it when required.

You can read [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1660) for more info on this

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Basically I'd to use action "displayPersonalInformation" in my Employee component which is a presentation component and hence not redux aware. For which you have suggested me to put the entry of it in mapDispatchToProps(as shown by you) and have access to it. Now I'm trying to make it generic. 
If I want to use any action in the presentation component, then I have to have that action entry in my mapDispatchToProps. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah that should do. Ideally you should create one `EmployeeContainer` and pass `mapDispatchToProps` to your `Employee` component from your container as props.

Comment: How will the mapDispatchToProps look then? Because I will have a set of action creators that might be used in that component. Will each action creator have a separate entry in the mapDispatchToProps? And summarizing again, "bindActionCreators" will never be used in mapDispatchToProps.

Comment: @Harikirat, I'm still getting the error "display is not a function" in bindActionCreators.js file after putting mapDispatchToProps in my connect function.

Comment: Can you share your code once? I am updating answer for multiple dispatch actions

Comment: Will share the code soon. But look at this example of how they have used bindActionCreators in mapDispatchToProps. https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used `bindActionCreators`, `redux` would `dispatch` the action whenever you call the action creator i.e `displayPersonalInformation` in your case.

As @Harkirat Saluja mentioned in his answer, if you have used `mapDispatchToProps` then your component would not have the `dispatch` function bound with `props`.

But still if you want to have `dispatch` with `props` (not best practice), then you can have something like,

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
   return { dispatch, ...actions: bindActionCreators({ actionCreators }, dispatch) }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Can I not tie my actions to props at all in redux. Because that was my core problem. Pardon me if I'm sounding silly.

Comment: I'm still getting the error "display is not a function" in bindActionCreators.js file after putting mapDispatchToProps in my connect function as Harikirat said.

Comment: I am not able to get why would you want bind dispatch props when you already have it in mapDispatchToProps.

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja if you want to have `dispatch` function with `props` (not best practice), then you can have it as i shown. Read my answer with bit more care

Comment: @Harkirat: Right, I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  class MainLayout extends React.component{
      render(){
        console.log(this.props.list);
        return(
            <div>
               <h1>mainlayout</h1>
             </div>
            );
        } 
    }
  function mapStateToProps(state) {
       return {
           list: state.listingReducer
       }
   }
   export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MainLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access your actions through props because you are assigning your actions to the action attribute. The way you bind your actions to your props you could access your functions through this.props.actions.myFunction. If you want to call your actions directly through props connect your actions to your props like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MainLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { bindActionCreators, } from 'redux';
import { connect, } from 'react-redux';

/**
 * Map redux actions to the Component's props
 * @param {*} dispatch The Redux store's dispatch method
 * @returns {*} Object
 */
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        yourActions,
    }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(MainLayout);
```